# Integration intervals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I was doing an exercise about calculating the mass and centre of mass of a plane region defined by $P=\{(x,y): \vert y\vert \leq x \leq 1\}.$ I came across the integration interval for the integral with respect to $x$ which is obvious, but I couldn't get the integration interval for the $y$ variable. I was wondering if some of you could give me a hand.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: y goes from -x to +x as x goes from 0 to 1.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you draw the integration region in the plane?

Answer (score 0):

Such integral can be written in two ways, depending on which integration you're doing first:
$$ \iint_P f(x,y) dx dy = \int_{-1}^1 \Big(\int_{|y|}^1 f(x,y) dx\Big) dy = \int_0^1 \Big(\int_{-x}^x f(x,y) dy\Big) dx $$